# JavaScrip React - Redux calculator issue

Tags: javascript, react-redux, calculator

First of all I apologise for the code ive provided it is pretty messy but I cannot fix it now. My calculator works for the first time when I type values and after pressing equal sign things start act confusing.my redux history property has to save the result of the last calculation however it splits the result for example: 174 -> 1,7,4. The code was written on codepen so the libs we've connected behind the scenes

```
const UPDATE = 'UPDATE';
const RESTART = 'RESTART';
const SOLVE = 'SOLVE';
const CONT = 'CONT';
const regexp = /[+*/]/;
const regex = /[\(\)]/g;
const update = (inputValue) => {
  return {
    type: 'UPDATE',
    input: inputValue
  }
}
const restart = () => {
  return {
    type: 'RESTART'
  }
}
const cont = () => {
  return {
    type: 'CONT'
  }
}
const calc = () => {
  return{
    type: 'SOLVE'
  }
}

const initialState = {
  history: [],
  output: ''
}

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch(action.type){
    case 'UPDATE':
    return {
      ...state,
      history: [...state.history, action.input],
    }
    break;
    case 'RESTART':
      return state = initialState;
    break;
    case 'SOLVE':
      console.log(state.history)

      const app = state.history.map((ele) => {
       return ele.replace(regex, "").toString()
});
      console.log('--------------------------------------')
      const divide = '/';
      const multiply = '*';
      while(app.includes('/') || app.includes('*')){
        let priores;
        if(app.includes('/')){
          const divideIndex = app.findIndex((element) => element === '/');
    priores = parseFloat(app[divideIndex - 1]) / parseFloat(app[divideIndex + 1]);
    app.splice(divideIndex - 1, 3, priores.toString());
  } else if (app.includes('*')) {
    const multiplyIndex = app.findIndex((element) => element === '*');
    priores = parseFloat(app[multiplyIndex - 1]) * parseFloat(app[multiplyIndex + 1]);
    app.splice(multiplyIndex - 1, 3, priores.toString());
  }
        }
      if(app.length == 1){
        return {
        ...state, output: app, history: app
      }
      }
      let result = parseFloat(app.slice(0, 1));
      for(let i = 0; i < app.length; i++){
    if (app[i] == '+') {
      if(app[i + 1].includes('.')){
        result *= 1000;
        result += parseFloat(app[i + 1]) * 1000;
        result /= 1000;
      }else{
      result += parseFloat(app[i + 1]);
      }
    } else if (app[i] == '-') {
      if(app[i + 1].includes('.')){
        result *= 1000;
        result -= parseFloat(app[i + 1]) * 1000;
        result /= 1000;
      }else{
      result -= parseFloat(app[i + 1]);
      }
    }
      }
      return {
        ...state, output: result.toString(), history: result.toString()
      }
      break;
    case 'CONT':
      return {...state, output: ''}
      break;
    default:
      return state;
    break;
  }
}

const store = Redux.createStore(reducer);


//React
class Calculator extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      input: '0',
      negativeCount: 0
    }
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.handleAc = this.handleAc.bind(this);
    this.handleOp = this.handleOp.bind(this);
    this.handleEquals = this.handleEquals.bind(this);
  }
  handleClick = (event) => {
    if(this.props.resul == ''){
      console.log(this.props.history)
      console.log(this.state.input)
      
    {this.state.input == "0" && this.setState({input: ''})}
    if(this.state.input == '+' || this.state.input == '/' || this.state.input == '*'){
      this.props.upd(this.state.input)
      this.setState({
        input: ''
      })
    }
    if(this.state.input == '-'){
      this.props.upd(this.state.input);
      this.setState({
        input: '',
        negativeCount: 0
      })
    }
    if(this.state.input.includes('(-') && this.state.input != '(-0)'){
      if(this.state.input.includes(')')){
      this.setState({
        input: this.state.input.replace(')', '')
      })
    this.setState((state)=> ({
      input: state.input.concat(val).concat(')'),
      negativeCount: 0
    }));
   }else{
     const val = event.target.innerText;
    this.setState((state)=> ({
      input: state.input.concat(val).concat(')'),
      negativeCount: 0
    }));
   }
      }else if(this.state.input != '(-0)'){

    const val = event.target.innerText;
    this.setState((state)=> ({
      input: state.input.concat(val),
      negativeCount: 0
    }));
  }

    const val = event.target.innerText;
        if(this.state.input == '(-0)'){
      this.setState({input: '(-'.concat(val).concat(')')})
    }
  }
  }
  
  handleOp = (event) => {
    if(this.props.resul != ''){
      this.props.cont();
    const op = event.target.innerText;
      this.setState({
      input: op
    })

      console.log('this s')
      console.log(this.props.history)
    }else{
    if(this.state.input != '(-0)'){
    let signOpCheck = regexp.test(this.state.input);
    let signCheck = this.state.input.split('');
    const op = event.target.innerText;
    if(op == '-' && this.state.negativeCount < 1 && signCheck[signCheck.length - 1] != '.' && this.state.input != "(-"){
      this.setState({
        input: op,
        negativeCount: this.state.negativeCount + 1
      })
    }else if(op == '-' && this.state.negativeCount > 0 && signCheck[signCheck.length - 1] != '.' && this.state.input != "(-"){
      this.props.upd(this.state.input);
      this.setState({
        input: '',
        negativeCount: 0
      })
       this.setState({
        input: '(-'
      })
    }
      
    if(signOpCheck == false && signCheck[signCheck.length - 1] != '.' && signCheck[signCheck.length - 1] != '-' && signCheck != '(-' && this.state.input != ''){
    this.props.upd(this.state.input);
         console.log(this.props.history)
    this.setState((state) => ({
      input: op,
      negativeCount: state.negativeCount + 1
    }))
   }
    }}
    
  }
  handleAc = () => {
    this.setState({
      input: '0',
      negativeCount: 0
    })
    this.props.res();
  }
  handleDecimal = () => {
    
    if(this.props.result == ''){
    let signOpCheck = regexp.test(this.state.input);
    {this.state.input == '0' && this.setState({last: '0'})}
    let dotCheck = this.state.input.includes('.');
    if(dotCheck == false  && signOpCheck == false && this.state.input != "(-"){
      if(this.state.input[this.state.input.length - 1] == ')'){
        this.setState({
         input: this.state.input.replace(')', '.')
        })
      }else if(dotCheck == false && signOpCheck == false && this.state.input != '-'){
    this.setState((state) => ({
      input: state.input.concat('.')
    }))}
  }}}
  handleEquals = () => {
    {this.state.input != '' && this.props.upd(this.state.input)}
    this.props.calculate();
        this.setState({
      input: this.props.resul
    });
  }
  
  render(){
    return(
      <div id = 'calc'>
      <div id = 'screen'>
        <div id = 'history'>{this.props.history}{this.state.input}</div>
        <div id = 'display'><div id = "output">{this.state.input}{this.props.resul}</div></div>
      </div>
      <div id = "keys">
        <button id = "clear" className="bg-danger" onClick = {this.handleAc}>AC</button>
        <button id = "divide" className="bg-secondary" onClick = {this.handleOp}>/</button>
        <button id = "multiply" className="bg-secondary" onClick = {this.handleOp}>*</button>
        <button id = "seven" onClick = {this.handleClick}>7</button>
        <button id = "eight" onClick = {this.handleClick}>8</button>
        <button id = "nine" onClick = {this.handleClick}>9</button>
        <button id = "subtract" class="bg-secondary" onClick = {this.handleOp}>-</button>
        <button id = "four" onClick = {this.handleClick}>4</button>
        <button id = "five" onClick = {this.handleClick}>5</button>
        <button id = "six" onClick = {this.handleClick}>6</button>
        <button id = "add" class="bg-secondary" onClick = {this.handleOp}>+</button>
        <button id = "one" onClick = {this.handleClick}>1</button>
        <button id = "two" onClick = {this.handleClick}>2</button>
        <button id = "three" onClick = {this.handleClick}>3</button>
        <button id = "equals" class="bg-primary" onClick={this.handleEquals}>=</button>
        <button id = "zero" onClick = {this.handleClick}>0</button>
        <button id = "decimal" onClick = {this.handleDecimal}>.</button>
      </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

  const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
      history: state.history,
      resul: state.output
    }
  }
  const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
      upd: (inputValue) => 
      dispatch(update(inputValue)),
      res: () => dispatch(restart()),
      calculate: () => dispatch(calc()),
      cont: () => 
      dispatch(cont())
    }
  }
  
const Provider = ReactRedux.Provider;
const connect = ReactRedux.connect;

const Connected = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Calculator);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store = {store}>
  <Connected />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('app'));
```

Note that if I multiply or divide without using + or - the calculator works as intended. however using + or - operations make it fill the history array with the result in the incorrect format.Some notes for your convenience: redux operates with the history array which held all the signs and numbers typed by a user. handleClick function is invoked when pressing any number. handleOp stand for handleOperator -+/*. the code has messy parts concerning the conditions for the handles. they were used to make calcs with negative signs possible.
after pressing the equal sign history holds correct format of the result but after pressing any operation sign and a number right after makes in held the splitter result.I know that the code is overcomplicated. At least I want to find out the reason for this bug, so I appreciate every effort to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue is in the `"SOLVE"` reducer case, towards the end a stringified value is saved as `state.history`.

```js
case 'SOLVE':
  return {
    ...state,
    output: result.toString(),
    history: result.toString()
  }
```

In the `"UPDATE"` case `state.history` is spread into a new array when adding an input value.

```js
case 'UPDATE':
  return {
    ...state,
    history: [...state.history, action.input],
  }
```

Spreading a string value creates a character array.

```js
const history = parseFloat("174").toString();
console.log([...history]);
```

I suspect you meant to create a new `history` array value.

```js
case 'SOLVE':
  return {
    ...state,
    output: result.toString(),
    history: [result.toString()]
  }
```

```js
const history = [parseFloat("174").toString()];
console.log([...history]);
```